# Ruby on Rails - Top 5 of a model: formal argument cannot be a constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list, constants, each

I'm having some issues trying to get the top 5 of my tutorial model to display on my index page.
I've got the following in the index method (for the index action) in my tutorial controller:

```
@TopTutorials = Tutorial.find(:all, :order => "views DESC", :limit => 5)
```

I then use this instance variable and try to loop through the top 5 in my index view:

```
<% @TopTutorials.each do |TopViewedTutorial| %>
<%= link_to TopViewedTutorial.name, show_tutorial_path(TopViewedTutorial.category_id, TopViewedTutorial.to_param) %>
<% end %>
```

I'm kind of new to looping through things like this and so I assume I've done something wrong. On loading up the index page I get the following error at the ".each do" line:

```
formal argument cannot be a constant
```

Could anyone help me out with this?

Best Regards,

Joe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change TopViewedTutorial to something starting with lowercase letter like topViewedTutorials. You could read more about ruby names here http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_names.html.

Comment: Ah - I see! I would have never thought the name of the block variable (or in this case constant!) would have affected anything. Worked a treat, thanks!

Comment: More than welcome. As far as I can understand you're new to Rails and Ruby. So, if you don't mind I would recommend you to be aware of the most common rails anti-pattern I see around us. Not to learn Ruby :)

Comment: Heh. I really need to get round to learning some more ruby sometime (I  got bored of running through general programming fundamentals for the nth time after the hello world lesson :P). Thanks again!